# Pycharm's TeXiFy - New Run Configuration For Each File?

Tags: compiling, ide

I'm writing my Ph.D. thesis in LaTeX and wanted to give the Pycharm IDE a try since I'm using it for all my coding. I've been using Sublime up until recently. I got it all up and running, but I'm extremely confused about the run configurations. From what I can tell, I need to add a custom LaTeX and BibTeX configuration manually for every single LaTeX file I write. Is that true?

For example, if I have three files in my project named main.tex, ch1.tex, ch2.tex, do I need to manually go into Run -> Edit Configurations -> Add Configuration -> ... for every single one of those files? I can't just run one tex file and have it compile automatically?  I should explicitly mention that I want to compile each file individually, as opposed to only compiling one "main" file with multiple "subfiles".

I hope that makes sense, please let me know what I need to clarify.

For reference, I'm on Mac OS and am using Pycharm version 2023.3.3.

Comment: I don't use PyCharm myself but it seems you can use a special variable representing the current filename, which probably means you can use one configuration for all files (see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32010641/how-to-use-current-file-as-parameter-to-run-configuration-in-pycharm)

Comment: @Marijn, I tried that but couldn't get it to work :(